# Need a way to annotate service methods following repository pattern

Tags: java, playframework, annotations, repository-pattern

I'm trying to refactor the existing code base of one of my project following Repository pattern, so that i can make the project more re-usable and testable.

I've written services, repositories, when I try to set Authentication, Authorization and Transactional annotation on service layer, I am facing issues.
  These annotations works only on controller level, but not on service layer, so I want a way for annotate service methods.
  Is it possible to do so?

It would be helpful, if someone points me samples using repository pattern on Play framework or better way to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication and authorization only make sense on a request, so sticking them on anything but a controller method is not going to work either way.

Transactional is just a helper annotation to wrap the entire request in a JPA transaction. It is usually advisable to do the wrapping yourself anyway, so you don't really need that. Example taken from [the documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJPA#Using-play.db.jpa.JPAApi):

```
@Inject
private JPAApi jpaApi;

public void updateSomething() {
    // do something with the entity manager, per instance
    // save, update or query model objects.
    jpaApi.withTransaction(() -> {
        EntityManager em = jpaApi.em();
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery("update people set active = 1 where age > 18");
        query.executeUpdate();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes, we can do that by the way you have mentioned, but some cases i do need to have series of persist in my service which one depends on another. For instance, we persist parent first which will be in separate transaction and next child which will be another transaction. If my child persist fails, it won't revert the parent persist. Eventually i need a way to wrap my service in single transaction.